# How to show timestamp's value as datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, timestamp

please tell me how to show the value of timestamp field of a table in datetime format (human understandable). and also how to use it in comparison while querying it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example what you mean under timestamp field ?

Comment: @Taras: i have taken a column whose datatype is timestamp which is maintaing its versioning. i wants to konw that can i get it/ show it as a datetime format.

Comment: Now is more clear. See answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done. The `TIMESTAMP` datatype is misnamed - the name has been deprecated in favour of `ROWVERSION` in SQL 2008, which is a much clearer name.

`TIMESTAMP` stores an incrementing value which changes every time a row is updated.

If you want last updated dates stored against each row, you will need to add a `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME` to your table and update it with the current date on each update.

Answer (score 2):

You mean `timestamp` data type I think - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

You **can't** convert it to `datetime`. According to the documentation in the link above :

```
> The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type.
```